# Unexplained crash AFTER sending an email using MFMailComposer

Tags: iphone

In my app, I have email sending code.

It's quite plain-vanilla (pasted at end of question).

What happens is the following sequence:
- Click the "EMAIL" button of my app, that calls the sendEmail method
- Click the To field
- Type an email address
- Click the MFMailComposer Send button
- The email is sent (and arrives - I typically set my own email address)
- The application crashes... with this stack crawl:

```
2011-07-25 11:21:21.179 MyApp[2769:3d0b] -[__NSCFString searchQuery:returnedResults:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3c3410
2011-07-25 11:21:21.201 MyApp[2769:3d0b] uncaughtExceptionHandler
2011-07-25 11:21:21.202 MyApp[2769:3d0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString searchQuery:returnedResults:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3c3410'
```

What I notice is the following:
1. As I type the the To address, the debugger output shows **CPSqliteStatementSendResults: interrupted**
2. If I add a *setToRecipients* (effectively "hard-coding" the *To* email address), the application doesn't crash...

Any ideas? (code below)

```
- (void)sendEmail:(id)sender {
    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [controller setSubject:@"The Subject"];

    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                        error:(NSError*)error;
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Sending Failed");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Message not sent");
            break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other function with name 'searchQuery' ?

Comment: No - no where in my code do I have a method named 'searchQuery'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to release the MFMailComposeViewController immediately but in his delegate method didFinishWithResult (at the very end).

Comment: All sample code I saw (including http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Listings/Classes_MailComposerViewController_m.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865-Classes_MailComposerViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6) shows a release immediately. Any specific reason you suspect this?

Comment: No, you are completely right. I'm just forgetting how things work since ARC. ;)
Here's what i've found in the documentation:
 `Important: ...Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.`
That seems to me that you have to provide a starting recipient but correct me if i'm wrong. I've worked just one time with the mail composer for now.

Comment: I believe this doesn't mean the field must be set - it just means (IMHO) that _if_ you want to set these fields, you must set _before_ presenting the controller. Don't you read it this way?

Comment: Yes, you may be right again. ;) sry, can't resolve the problem.

Comment: Well, while this proposed solution causes a leak, I did use it and the problem did go away (i allowed this small leak as it was really time pressured...) - so I'll still accept the answer...